# Javascript parsing a string that might or might not be valid JSON inside? (extracting an array from a string)

Tags: javascript, json

I have a property of an object which is always a string. The string however might just be regular characters or it might contain a stringified array of values.

If its a regular string of characters then I want to just pass the value through but if its an array, then I want to do some further processing on it in its array form.

I can use `JSON.parse(myValue)` which is great for extracting an array but throws an error if its a regular string.

I could maybe do something like:

```
let extractedVal = '';

try {
  extractedVal = JSON.parse(myValue)
} catch (e) {
  extractedVal = myValue
}
```

but this doesn't feel right as the `let` variable feels messy and the try/catch feels like its not being used correctly as I'm not doing anything with the error etc... .

Is there a better way or a suggested best practice to achieve this?

Comment: Why is the try/catch not being used correctly? You're trying something and then catching the error.

Comment: What you are doing is perfectly reasonable, and exactly what try/catch is designed for.  If you are going to repeat this construct more than a couple of times then it can easily be turned into a function that returns either a string or an object/array (if 'JSON.parse' succeeds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `try`/`catch` in this situation is just fine. I wouldn't assign an initial value to the `extractedVal` variable, though, since you're reassigning it in both branches, just remove that `= ''` initializer.

You *could* change it slightly:

```
let extractedVal = value;
try {
    extractedVal = JSON.parse(extractedVal);
    // ...more processing here...
} catch {
    // ...ignore...
}
```

but frankly I think your original is just as clear, here with a couple of tweaks:

```
let extractedVal;
try {
    extractedVal = JSON.parse(value);
    // ...more processing here...
} catch {
    extractedVal = value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks TJ, good clarification that this is a legitimate try/catch use case. I've always previously assumed try/catch was designed really for handling error catching and I was using it as a bit of a hack here but good to know using it like this is would be seen as fine.

Didn't know about CR, so thanks also for that!

Comment: @user3856343 - You're right, `try`/`catch` is for catching errors. Since we don't have a version of `JSON.parse` that returns a flag value for invalid JSON rather than throwing, we have to use it and handle the semi-expected error. I've always kind of liked the .Net approach to things like that: They usually have a function (like [`int.Parse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse)) that parses or throws and also a function (like [`int.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse)) that tells you whether it worked without throwing.

Comment: I don't like the exact way the `TryXYZ` methods work (they take a reference to a variable, something we don't have in JavaScript), but I kind of like the idea of them. (I suspect if they were added to the .Net lib *now*, with the modern language features available, they would have been designed differently. `int.TryParse` could return `int?` for instance, but that wasn't there at the beginning.) Sorry, digression! :-)